# Bypass function "out" parameters

Tags: delphi

Some functions need a variable to send out a value. But sometimes I don't need that value and don't want to define a variable to use it as function `out` parameter. Like this:

```
procedure test(out SomeVar: string);
begin
   //...
end;
```

I want to execute this safely:

```
test;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a wrapper:

```
procedure test(); overload;
var
    SomeVar : string;
begin
    test(SomeVar);
end;
```

Note: You'll also have to mark the other version with `overload`, or you can call your wrapper something other than `test`, and remove the `overload`.

Another option: declare a dummy variable somewhere (at the top of your unit, maybe):

```
var 
  DummyStr : string;
```

Then you don't have to declare a new variable every time you want to call the function.

```
test(DummyStr);
```

Comment: Is this the only way? IDK can I use `nil` or something else instead of a variable?

Comment: Afraid not. If a procedure specifies an out parameter, you must supply the parameter.

Comment: So called "other option" fails under multi-threaded scenarios

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right. Even if it should not "fail" in most cases, since the `DummyStr` variable content will just be ignored. If two threads update it at once, it would not break anything, *unless* the `out SomeVar` variable is used within the `Test()` procedure after having been set. In this case, it would be a nightmare bug to track at runtime. So I would not recommend using it, unless you use a `threadvar DummyStr: string` but I suspect it is slow and resource consuming (threadvars slots are scarce).

Comment: @Arnaud TLS slots are scarce, but threadvar slots are not. All threadvars in a module share the same TLS slot.

Answer (score 4):

You can overload the procedure:

```
procedure test(out SomeVar: string); overload;
begin
   //...
end;

procedure test; overload; inline;
var dummy: string;
begin
  test(dummy);
end;
```

Note the `inline` keyword, available since Delphi 2005 AFAIR.

What I usually do is to use a pointer instead of `out` parameter:

```
procedure test(SomeVarP: PString=nil); 
begin
   if SomeVarP<>nil then
     SomeVarP^ := ....
end;
```

As such you can use:

```
var s: string;

test;
test(@s);
```

Comment: I think it was introduced in 2006, not 2005

Answer (score 2):

Use a pointer:

```
procedure test(SomeVar: PString = nil);
begin
  if SomeVal <> nil then SomeVar^ := '';
  //...
  if SomeVal <> nil then SomeVar^ := ...;
end;
```

```
test;
```

```
var
  s: string;

test(@s);
```

Comment: There is some system function that has `out` parameter and I looking for a solution for them. I think a wrapper(@Blorgbeard) is the only solution (If I don't want to use a global variable). Thanks